# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS) while merging two arrays

Tags: php

What is the problem here?

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
$arr4 = [...$arr1, ...$arr2];
print_r($arr4);
```

Comment: PHP version too old ...? This should not throw any errors from 7.4 on, https://3v4l.org/ImrKA

Comment: This was added in PHP 7.4 - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.unpack-inside-array. Before that, you'll need to merge the arrays another way (`$arr1 + $arr2`, `array_merge`, etc etc etc)

Comment: Yes. The problem was the outdated PHP version... Thanks!

Comment: Do not add `[Solved]` to your title. Either add a proper answer in the section below if you think it will help others, or consider deleting this question if it was a version issue (local to your setup, not likely to help others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
//$arr4 = [...$arr1, ...$arr2];  **[ Replace this line]**
$arr4 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($arr4);
```